# Could electron be antimatter?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, standard-model, conventions, antimatter

Could an electron be considered antimatter? Since annihilation occurs between the same types of particles and nucleons are baryons consisting of matter quarks, while electrons are leptons, they shouldn't annihilate, right?

Is there other physics that prevents electrons being considered as antimatter, like chirality for example? If yes, what?

Comment: conservation of quantum numbers keeps the electron in the matter side, and the positron the antimatter. Look at the standard model of particle physics, which is a precis of all the particle data up to now https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could electrons be a form of antimatter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66894/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identification of particles and anti-particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81787/)

Comment: The downvotes seem harsh. I asked basically this question a little while ago (see above) and it got 37 upvotes.